How do I verify no other calls on a moq that has sub-mocks?
In the following example, I'm getting some behavior I wouldn't expect:
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var mockGetter = new Mock<IHostedServiceGetter>();
    var mockService = new Mock<IHostedService>();

    mockGetter.Setup(i => i.Get()).Returns(mockService.Object);

    mockGetter.Object.Get();
    mockService.Object.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None);

    mockGetter.Verify(i => i.Get(), Times.Once);
    mockGetter.VerifyNoOtherCalls();
}

public interface IHostedServiceGetter
{
    public IHostedService Get();
}

This test fails, with the exception:
Moq.MockException : Mock<IHostedService:1>:
This mock failed verification due to the following unverified invocations:

   IHostedService.StartAsync(CancellationToken)

If I remove the call to mockService.Object.StartAsync(), the test passes.
I'm unclear on why this is happening.  I am attempting to verify all calls to mockGetter, without caring about calls to mockService.  I would think that the verifier would verify each mock object separately.  If I have 2 completely unrelated objects, I don't get a similar exception.  For example, this test passes:
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var mockGetter = new Mock<IHostedServiceGetter>();
    var mockService = new Mock<IHostedService>();

    mockGetter.Setup(i => i.Get()).Returns(new Mock<IHostedService>().Object);

    mockGetter.Object.Get();
    mockService.Object.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None);

    mockGetter.Verify(i => i.Get(), Times.Once);
    mockGetter.VerifyNoOtherCalls();
}

The only difference being that I'm not making a call to the "sub-mock" as I was in the first test.
What is going on here, and how can I get Moq to ignore calls to the sub-mock when verifying the parent mock?
Edit:
I figured out that by changing the mock to mockGetter.Setup(i => i.Get()).Returns(() => mockService.Object); the test suddenly starts working.  I still have no understanding of why this behaves as it does and would love an explanation if anyone has one.
